# Put transaction into stored procedure for cancelling all operations

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have oracles stored procedure, which performs 2 operation, delete and then update. my aim is update should always update one row, if more row updated, i want cancel both operations, this is my transaction i tried

```
BEGIN

  BEGIN transaction trans;
     (here is delete query)


      (here is update query)
     IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 1 THEN
            ROLLBACK TO tran;
    ELSE
          COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END;

END;
```

But this yields error `Error(5,23): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TRANS" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; The symbol ":=" was substituted for "TRANS" to continue.`

What is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 BEGIN
        (here is delete query)

        (here is update query)
        IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 1 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'rollbacked');
        END IF;
 END;
```

Stored procedures in oracle are transactional by default, if you have 2 query(delete and update) and you want abort both of them, no need additional `BEGIN transaction ...` or something like this

Comment: yes i want abort both query, this is soo simple, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you must use SAVEPOINTS, should be like this:

```
BEGIN 

SAVEPOINT tran;
     (here is delete query)


      (here is update query)
     IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 1 THEN
            ROLLBACK TO tran;
    ELSE
          COMMIT;
    END IF;
END;
```

However, for me it is not clear where you like to rollback, perhaps `SAVEPOINT tran;` should be put after `(here is delete query)` - depending on your requirements.

Comment: thank you, my requirement is cancel both query. i did this, thank you again